# ¿Cómo agregarle un ID a un texto que se repite?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un Post Type en Wordpress donde tengo el simbolo de Copyright ® pero quiero agregarle un codigo agregarle un id solo a ese texto como podria hacerlo? Hay alguna manera de hacerlo con JS?

```html
<header class="article-header">
   <h1>Company® Compensation</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: No entiendo: Quieres algo así  `<h1 id="mi_id"> ...` ??

Comment: <h1>Company®<--(Agregar el id a este simbolo) Compensation</h1>

Comment: algo como esto: `<h1>Company<span id="Copyright">®</span> Compensation</h1>` ??

Comment: Si efectivamente, pero ver la forma de hacerlo con JS para que detecte ese simbolo, ya que los textos son autogenerados.

Comment: Ok me quedan 2 dudas entonces. 1) puede haber más de un texto con ®, porque las ID deben ser únicas, si hay más de uno creo que es mejor usar class y 2) Este símbolo siempre va a estar dentro de "article-header" ???

Answer (score 1):

Para acceder a un elemento dentro del javascript generalmente se utilizan los id, y usas el método del DOM getElementById, pero también puedes acceder a los elementos usando la clase, pero este método te regresa un arreglo con todos los elementos de cierta clase, por eso en mi asignación al elemento utilizo la posición [0], si te das cuenta. Creo una string con una id para asignarle, y le modifico el innerHTML a el elemento que seleccioné, espero te sirva

```js
let myElem = document.getElementsByClassName("article-header");
const myId = "someCustomId"

myElem[0].innerHTML = "<h1 id='" + myId + "'>Company® Compensation</h1>"
```

```html
<header class="article-header">
</header>
```